# Passing queue as parameter in c

Tags: c, parameters, queue

I am passing queues like these between source files a.c and b.c

**File : a.c**

```
sq[a]=new_queue();

pthread_create(&st[a],NULL,sendPacket,sq[a]);
```

**File : b.c**

```
void *sendPacket(void *queue){

/* here i need to know which queue has come ,determine
   the index of queue how can I do it? */
}
```

Comment: Please update your title; the problem is not "passing queue as parameter".

Answer (score 1):

Create a more high-level representation of your queue. It seems the queue can be a `void *` (you're not showing its actual type, i.e. what does the `new_queue()` call return?), so embed that in a structure while adding the additional parameters:

```
struct queue_state {
    void *queue;
    int  index;
};
```

Then instantiate a structure, and pass a pointer to it to the thread function:

```
struct queue_state qsa = malloc(sizeof *qsa);
if(qsa != NULL)
{
  qsa->queue = new_queue();
  qsa->index = 4711; /* or whatever */
  pthread_create(&st[a], NULL, sendPacket, qsa);
}
```

Then the thread function can use the `struct` declaration to access all the fields. Of course, the declaration needs to be in a shared header (say `queue.h`) which is included from both C files.

Answer (score 1):

Your question description is very rough. But at least from what I understand, you actually need to pass 2 parameters to your function: the (pointer to) queue (which seems an array for me), and the index within this queue.

You may not pack both your parameters in a single variable of type `void*`. What you may do is declare a struct with all the needed parameters, fill it, and pass a pointer to it to your thread.

Like this (error handling omitted):

```
struct Params
{
    queue* m_Queue;
    size_t m_Idx;
};

// ...
Params* pParams = new Params;
pParams->m_Queue = sq;
pParams->m_Idx = a;

pthread_create(&st[a],NULL,sendPacket, pParams);


void *sendPacket(void *pPtr)
{
    Params* pParams = (Params*) pPtr;

    // ...

    delete pParams;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is easier if you just pass the index to the function:

```
void *sendPacket(int queue_idx) {
    queue_t *queue = &sq[queue_idx];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If in *b.c* you have access to `sq`, you can just pass the index to the queue.  Otherwise you can pass a struct containing the actual queue and the index